# Mongodb C#: how do i update embeded document/dictionary

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following user object.  How do i add a new liked or disliked friend for the user via mongodb update builder.  I started but i'm not able to get it working.  sample code below.  thank you

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Friend>> Friends{ get; set; }
}

public class Circle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the how the mongo json looks like

```
{
  "Email" : null,
  "Name" : "Nick",
  "Password" : null,
  "Friends" : {
    "Liked" : {
     "WER2343" : {
      "Name" : "Friend 1"
     }
    },
    "Disliked" : {
      "M3222343" : {
       "Name" : "Friend 2"
      }
     }
    },
   "_id" : ObjectId("513b5d84bfeddf1c8091530e")
}
```

This is the code i'm trying to get working

```
 public void AddFriend(User self, User friend, string circle)
    {

        IMongoQuery query = Query
            .And(Query<User>.EQ(t => t.Id, self.Id));

        IMongoUpdate update = Update<User>
            .Push(t => t.Friends)

        Collection.FindAndModify(query,null, update);

    }
```

Comment: Push works on mongo arrays. The nested dictionary results in a subdocument, which is not addressable by the operator except as a full value. Consider having a IEnumerable<Friend> property for  "LikedFriends" and "DislikedFriends" directly on User?

Comment: Nuk Nuk San is exactly right - you are not defining liked and disliked as arrays in MongoDB so you can only have one subdocument.  You want to store arrays of subdocuments it seems.  It's a very bad idea though - unless this is for a class or simple demo growing your documents like that will be very inefficient from performance point of view.